# create folder for each file and move file into folder

Tags: powershell

I need a command that can be run from the powershell to create a folder for each file (based on the file-name) in a directory and then move the file into the newly created folders.

Example :

**Starting Folder:**

```
Dog.jpg
Cat.jpg
```

The following command works great at creating a folder for each filename in the current working directory.

**Result Folder:**

\Dog\
\Cat\

```
Dog.jpg
Cat.jpg
```

**What I want to achieve is:**

```
\Dog\Dog.jpg
\Cat\Cat.jpg
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please update your question with what you are currently trying along with the specific issues/errors you are getting

Comment: What if you have multiple pictures of cats? (Cat.jpg, Cat1234.jpg, etc) ? What format is used to name those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
Function Create-FolderAndMoveFile
{
    param(
        [string]$folder
    )

    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Filter *.jpg

    foreach($file in $files)
    {
        $dir = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("$file")
        $dest = $("$folder\$dir")
        New-Item $dest -ItemType Directory

        Move-Item -Path $file.Fullname -Destination $dest
    }
}
```

Then you can call this function like `Create-FolderAndMoveFile -folder C:\YourSuperAwesomePath\`and it will create a folder for every .jpg file there is..

Hope this helps